# How would one *exclude* a tag from a page?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

This may seem like an odd request, but right now in Movies & TV there are dozens upon dozens of Game of Thrones questions.  I don't care about Game of Thrones, I can't answer their questions, nor do I particularly want to see references to their sordid and demonic tribulations.

Is there a setting where a user can exclude a tag, and never see anything tagged with said tag until they deem they wish to see it again?  Doesn't seem like a difficult request; just add an additional piece to the WHERE clause that brings back the questions to display.

Any chance we can do something like this?  It would sort of be like the opposite of the Favorites tags.  In some stacks, I think this could be quite useful.

Comment: It already exists with "ignored tags", it's explained how to hide them in the FAQ

Comment: BEAUTIFUL! Except the User/Preferences thing must have gotten changed at some point, it's hidden a little now. I had to go into my profile, then click "Edit Profile And Settings", then on the left side under Site Preferences there's a Settings link and it's in there.

Comment: [/users/preferences](/users/preferences) should still take you straight to that page